# как видеть текущее значение в DBLookupComboBox

Tags: база-данных, delphi

Как сделать что бы можно было видеть текущее значение в `DBLookupComboBox`,  и иметь возможность выбрать другие. При закрытии формы значения сохраняются в бд, а при открытии `DBLookupComboBox` пустой, а нужно что бы было видно значение из бд. Не знаю как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста.
Пробовала так:

```
if cbType_p.Text<>' ' then
  cbType_p.Visible;
```

на на последнюю строку вылазит ошибка

> [Error] PACTEDIT.PAS(223): Statement expected, but expression of type
>   'Boolean' found

Answer (score 0):

DBLookupComboBox показывает показывает значение поля с именем `ListField` из датасета `ListSource.Dataset` для записи, у которой значения поля с именем `KeyField` совпадает со значением поля `DataField` текущей записи датасета `DataSource.Dataset`.

Отсюда возможные причины пустого комбобокса

1. Датасет `DataSource.Dataset` закрыт
2. Поле `DataSource.Dataset.FieldByName(DataField)` равно NULL
3. Датасет `ListSource.Dataset` закрыт
4. В датасете нет записи для которой выполняется условие

   ```
   DataSource.Dataset.FieldByName(DataField).AsVariant =
       ListSource.Dataset.FieldByName(KeyField).AsVariant
   ```
5. Такая запись есть, но поле `ListSource.Dataset.FieldByName(ListField)` равно NULL

Comment: На сколько я понимаю это и есть условие для отображения данных, спасибо попробую DataSource.Dataset.FieldByName(DataField).AsVariant =
    ListSource.Dataset.FieldByName(KeyField).AsVariant

Comment: Условий 5. Если выполнится хоть одно из них - данных не будет